# Wordpress's is_plugin_active_for_network function not working for multisites

Tags: php, wordpress

I am in need to do some operation if user clicks on **Network Activate** button on my WP Plugin (in WP Multisite).

But I noticed that Wordpress's is_plugin_active_for_network function not working for multisites when I press the Network Activate button from the Main Administrator Panel.

It returns nothing, and hence the

```
if(is_plugin_active_for_network('abc/abc.php'))
```

is not fulfilled.

However when the Network is already Network Activated then the function - **is_plugin_active_for_network** is working fine (It returns **1** - i.e. **true**).

Can anyone please tell me how can I check whether the **Network Activate** button is clicked by the main administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to check for Network Wide activation on your plugin (as opposed to activation on a single site) then you need to check the boolean variable that gets passed to your activation function.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate' );

function activate( $network_wide ) {

    // $network_wide will be TRUE if activation is network wide
    if ( $network_wide  ) {

        ... Do Stuff ...

    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I am using OOP approach in activating the plugin. $network_wide does not have any value all the times.

Comment: The only thing OOP should change is the callback code. Then it should look like this... `array( 'MyPluginClass', 'activate' )`. When/how is it not working?

Comment: I think this $network_wide varibale no longer works on Wordpress new versions. I am using the OOP approach and **register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array($my_plugin_class_object, 'activate') );** and in the function **activate** which is inside the class I have written **function activate($network_wide) { print_r($network_wide);die(); }**
but nothing is printed, means the $network_wide is not found. :(